# Reading an Existing Join

Tags: arcobjects, c#, attribute-joins

Confused again.  I was finally able to run ArcCatalog and create a join in my map document (I will do the deed programmatically eventually) but I was interested in how a join looked once it was created. However, when I iterate thru the layers and read the fields associated to each layer using get_Field(index) in C# I see no joined fields. How can I read (and use) an existing join?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [IDisplayTable](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriCarto/IDisplayTable.htm):

```
//psuedocode
IDisplayTable pDisplayTable = pFeatureLayer as IDisplayTable;
ITable ptable = pDisplayTable.DisplayTable;
```

Comment: That works, except, why are the fields marked not visible showing up and why are the alias names I set in the layer still using the old field names?